# Reshaping DataFrame; Melt/Pivot

Tags: python, pandas, transformation, data-modeling

Body:

Problem:

I have a wide DataFram that I'm struggling to reshape and aggregate using pandas.

Sample Data:

| Unnamed: 1 | Unnamed: 2 | Unnamed: 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bezeichnung (Bezirksregion) | Straftaten \n-insgesamt- | Raub |
| Mitte | 81178 | 823 |
| Tiergarten Süd | 4113 | 37 |
| Regierungsviertel | 6251 | 41 |
| Alexanderplatz | 18999 | 163 |

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Sample data
data = """
,Unnamed: 1,Unnamed: 2,Unnamed: 3
3,Bezeichnung (Bezirksregion),Straftaten \\n-insgesamt-,Raub
4,Mitte,81178,823
5,Tiergarten Süd,4113,37
6,Regierungsviertel,6251,41
7,Alexanderplatz,18999,163
"""

# Load data into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=0)

# Display the DataFrame
print("Loaded DataFrame:")
print(df)
```

Desired Output:

```
desired_output = {
    'Region': ['Mitte', 'Tiergarten Süd', 'Regierungsviertel', 'Alexanderplatz'],
    'Crimes': ['Straftaten -insgesamt-', 'Straftaten -insgesamt-', 'Raub', 'Raub'],
    'count': [81178, 4113, 41.33, 163],
}
```

| Region | Crimes | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mitte | Straftaten -insgesamt- | 81178 |
| Tiergarten Süd | Straftaten -insgesamt- | 4113 |
| Regierungsviertel | Raub | 41.33 |
| Alexanderplatz | Raub | 163 |

Current Approach:

```
melted_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=[df.columns[0]], var_name='crime', value_name='crime_count')
```

Issues:

Result not as expected:

|  | crime | crime_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bezeichnung (Bezirksregion) | Unnamed: 2 | Straftaten \n-insgesamt- |
| Mitte | Unnamed: 2 | 81178 |
| Tiergarten Süd | Unnamed: 2 | 4113 |
| Regierungsviertel | Unnamed: 2 | 6251 |
| Alexanderplatz | Unnamed: 2 | 18999 |

**Assistance Requested:**

How can I reshape the DataFrame to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Why are you discarding half of your data?

Comment: where in the code am I doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need to rename the columns using the first row of your data, then melt it on the first column and rename the resultant dataframe's columns:

```
res = (df
    .set_axis(df.iloc[0], axis=1)
    .drop(df.index[0])
    .melt(id_vars=df.iloc[0,0])
    .set_axis(['Region', 'Crimes', 'Count'], axis=1)
)
```

Output for your sample data:

```
              Region                    Crimes  Count
0              Mitte  Straftaten \n-insgesamt-  81178
1     Tiergarten Süd  Straftaten \n-insgesamt-   4113
2  Regierungsviertel  Straftaten \n-insgesamt-   6251
3     Alexanderplatz  Straftaten \n-insgesamt-  18999
4              Mitte                      Raub    823
5     Tiergarten Süd                      Raub     37
6  Regierungsviertel                      Raub     41
7     Alexanderplatz                      Raub    163
```